How to make image texture generation more efficient SFML
I'm writing a 3 particle simulation using c++ and the SFML library for graphics.
The goal of the simulation is to both show the particles and to generate a visual heatmap of the magnitude of their force distribution.
The problem has been that each approach I've taken to drawing the background heatmap has been incredibly inefficient to the point where the code is essentially unable to run, it compiles, but the simulation has an abysmal frame-rate.
What my approach has been, so far, is to sample the force acting on a test particle at each point in space, take the magnitude of the force, and color the section of the window accordingly.
Realizing that calculating the force for each pixel was unreasonable, I tried removing that section of the code entirely, only to find that the frame-rate was still incredibly low, meaning that simply the action of altering pixel coloration was too computationally intensive.
Now, I've previously also tried using the rectangle objects included in the library to draw a more pixelated version of the heat-map, thinking this would be more efficient, but I similarly ran in to the same low frame-rate problem.
To put it in perspective, without any force-coloring it runs at ~60+ FPS, but when I add in the code that's supposed to alter the background brightness this shoots down to ~3 FPS, I would like it to run at least at 30 FPS.
This is the code I'm currently using to generate a background texture and alter the pixel colors, with the setup code here:
    int xsize = 1600;
    int ysize = 1000;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(xsize, ysize), "Particles");

    sf::Image backgroundImage;
    backgroundImage.create(xsize, ysize, sf::Color::Black);

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < ysize; y++) {
            sf::Uint8 r = 0;
            sf::Uint8 g = 0;
            sf::Uint8 b = 0;
            backgroundImage.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color(r, g, b));
        }
    }

    sf::Texture backgroundTexture;
    backgroundTexture.loadFromImage(backgroundImage);
    sf::Sprite backgroundSprite(backgroundTexture);

To avoid confusion I should preface that the variable magnitude is the magnitude of the force, and the variable force is supposed to be some function on the magnitude such that its values are always between 0 and 1.
And the actual drawing here with the force variable set to a constant for all pixels temporarily:
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
            for (unsigned int y = 0; y < ysize; y++) {
                //sim.setForce(x,y,0,0,0);
                //double magnitude = sqrt((sim.getforce(1)*sim.getforce(1))+(sim.getforce(2)*sim.getforce(2)));
                //double force = (1-(1/(magnitude+1)));
                double force = 0.25;
                sf::Color pixelColor = backgroundImage.getPixel(x, y);

                // Calculate the new brightness values by scaling them with the force
                float r = pixelColor.r * brightnessFactor;
                float g = pixelColor.g * brightnessFactor;
                float b = pixelColor.b * brightnessFactor;

                // Ensure that the colors stay within the valid range [0, 255]
                r = manualClamp(r);
                g = manualClamp(g);
                b = manualClamp(b);

                // Update the pixel in the image
                backgroundImage.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color(static_cast<sf::Uint8>(r), static_cast<sf::Uint8>(g), static_cast<sf::Uint8>(b)));
            }
        }
        
        backgroundTexture.update(backgroundImage);

And the method manualClamp:
sf::Uint8 manualClamp(float value) {
    return static_cast<sf::Uint8>(std::min(std::max(value, 0.0f), 255.0f));
}

To reiterate, I'm trying to find a way to alter the brightness of the background so that it shows the magnitude of the force at that point, like a heat-map.
The force is calculated with a 1 over radius squared distribution.
I'm looking for a way to do this that can run at a decent speed.
My compiler is MinGW, but the actual compile commands that are run I'm not sure of since the compilation is handled by an extension given to us by my school, this is for a computer science 1 class.
I'm relatively inexperienced in graphics and c++, I would appreciate some guidance on the proper approach to this sort of problem.

First thing to check always is whether you are compiling with optimizations enabled (look for -O2 or -O3) in the compilation flags. Alternatively, you may be building in debug mode instead of release mode.

sf::Image::SetPixel is not inlined, so you could get better performance by getPixelsPtr then indexing the pixels yourself (even more since the compiler can vectorize the code). though i think the code is bandwidth limited if anything, so if you enable optimizations you won't run into any problem.

I also noticed you are iterating over the image in a column-major fashion. Swap your for loops around so it is row-first.
